# Jenkins API Token

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I want to print my API token in the job console

[image: Console]

How to print it in the job console, is there any variable to access API token

other than going through the link

http://localhost:8080/user/{UserName}/configure

I want to access the API token via variable so that i can pass it to my REST call which in turn uses token to access jenkins

Comment: Not the best practice from a security perspective, but you can set it a a GLOBAL variable "MY_JENKINS_API_TOKEN" and have your scripts access it that way.

Comment: @PatriceM. is there any default variable Jenkins would provide, with out the  user setting it manually.

Comment: Not to my knowledge